# How to "expand" python timeseries

Tags: python

I have some data I must crunch in my app, and I don't know how to do it in a reasonably understandable way.

We have an undetermined series of data, that comes in diferent intervals. The intervals can be hourly, daily, weekly... For example:

```
hourly_data = {
    'interval': '1h',
    'data': [('05/10/2014 00:00', 10),
             ('05/10/2014 01:00', 11),
             ('05/10/2014 03:00', 6),
             ('05/10/2014 04:00', 8),
             ...
            ]
}

daily_data = {
    'interval': '1d',
    'data': [('05/10/2014 00:00', 87),
             ('05/11/2014 00:00', 73),
             ('05/12/2014 00:00', 86),
             ('05/13/2014 00:00', 99),
             ...
            ]
}
```

I need to compare this data. Let's say the data is the production of a factory, and I need to calculate the percentage of the complete daily production achieved in each hour. I would need to loop over the `hourly_data` list, and compare the value with the corresponding value in `daily_data`.

The complex part comes when we don't know how many series we must "compare" with this system (in the example there are only two, but can be more), nor the intervals that each of this series will have. All I know is that I must loop over the series following the system I described.

All the possible solutions that come to my mind are stupidly and absolutely hard to read. How would you face this algorithm?

**EDIT**

Answering to @user3727843, the interval options are pretty narrow: hourly, daily, weekly and monthly. That's all. What I want to "learn" from the data is completely arbitrary. I've explained the percentage example because is easy to understand, but I would want to build any kind of relationship.

I think the most versatile way of solving this is to "expand" the data to match the smallest interval. Something like this:

```
expanded_data = [
    [('05/10/2014 00:00', 10), ('05/10/2014 00:00', 87)],
    [('05/10/2014 01:00', 11), ('05/10/2014 00:00', 87)],
    ....
    [('05/11/2014 16:00', 7), ('05/11/2014 00:00', 93)],
    [('05/11/2014 17:00', 11), ('05/11/2014 00:00', 93)],
    ....
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its going to be a little messy no matter how you do it. It would be nice to know the full range of series data possible (such as yearly? or by the minute data?). From there you should determine what you are comparing and in what units. Using your example lets say your base comparison is going to be percent produced per hour with respect to the whole day. You can decide your base units will be per-hour/per-day. Then anything you get in a different unit, you can convert to hours and days.

The issue with your question is that we need to know what you want to "learn" from the data. Is it just the example percentage mentioned above? or is it a lot more of similar items. And when you say "compare multiple series" do you mean create a table of differences? We need more info about your question to really help, but hopefully this gives you a start.

EDIT:

Expanding the timeseries to the smallest unit is a good start. As for building on relationships, you are simply going to have a lot of if statements. What you could do is develop a number of basic math functions to compare your series. These could include percentages of correlating data in two series, differences, etc. You could also use sets to compare the data or get differences:

```
a = set(seriesA)
b= set(seriesB)
a.difference(b)  #ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html
```

Once you have developed a number of these functions you can simplify the rest of your comparison code to simply calling the operations you want in order to construct your comparison.

Comment: I've edited the question to answer your suggestions.

Comment: The maths of the comparison are not the problem. Actually, it's already written. The problem is how to write the data lists expansion in an reasonably legible way